# In AndEngine, where to call entity update methods?

Tags: java, android, andengine, updates

I'm using AndEngine and I adopted a Component-Entity Model to developing my game. My question is in an AndEngine setup, where and how should I invoke the update methods of my entities (and their components)?

I've only started using AndEngine two days ago, so forgive me for any noobity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **AndEngine**, for your *Entity* to have an update method that gets invoked at every frame, its class must implement the `IUpdateHandler` interface.

This will force you to override the `public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)` and `public void reset()` methods.

You then place your "update code" in the body of `onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)`.

The instantiated object implementing the `IUpdateHandler` interface then must be registered in your `Scene` object via the `registerUpdateHandler(IUpdateHandler updateHandler)`.

Here's an example code:

**Entity** class with the update method.

```
public class Entity implements IUpdateHandler
{
    // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
    {
            // Update code here
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
            // Reset code here
    }     
}
```

And then in the initialization block of your `SimpleBaseGameActivity` where you have the main scene declared as

```
Scene mainScene;
```

You register the Entity like this:

```
Entity entity = new Entity();

this.mainScene.registerUpdateHandler(entity);
```